# Email campaign failing to initialize

Tags: exm

When submitting a large regular email campaign, it fails with the following exception:

```
ERROR Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchQueueItemDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.GetValueFromSourceRow(Int32 destRowIndex, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& isDataFeed, Boolean& isNull)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ReadWriteColumnValueAsync(Int32 col)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyColumnsAsync(Int32 col, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyRowsAsync(Int32 rowsSoFar, Int32 totalRows, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.SqlDbEcmDataProvider.AddToDispatchQueue(Guid messageId, MessageType messageType, IEnumerable`1 recipients, Dictionary`2 customPersonTokens, Dictionary`2 customQueryStringParameters)
at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchManager.Queue(Int32 threadIndex, IEntityBatchEnumerator`1 recipients, Int32 abTestRecipients, DispatchNewsletterArgs args, Int32 enqueueBatchSize)
```

Does anyone know the cause and steps to take to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchManager.Queue` is trying to queue all the applicable contacts in the list(s) that are selected when creating the email. This issue can occur if one or more contacts is missing the `Alias` identifier.

You can use the following code to find these contacts on the particular list and remove them from the list and log the result

```
var listId = Guid.Parse("74bd7b7d-1b54-48cd-ba3a-d67e16665eb7");

int batchSize = 200; // Size of the batch
string[] facets =
{
    CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation,
    CollectionModel.FacetKeys.ListSubscriptions,
    CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList
}; // Contact facets to retrieve
var contactListProvider = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContactListProvider>();
var contactProvider = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContactProvider>();
var subscriptionService = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISubscriptionService>();
var contactList = contactListProvider.Get(listId, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var contactBatchEnumerator = contactProvider.GetContactBatchEnumerator(
    contactList,
    batchSize,
        facets);
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/InvalidEmail.csv"), $"ContactID,IdentifierSource,Identifier,PrimaryEmail" + Environment.NewLine);
while (contactBatchEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var contacts = contactBatchEnumerator.Current;

    try
    {
        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            try
            {

                var email = contact.Emails()?.PreferredEmail?.SmtpAddress?.Trim()?.ToLower();
                var emailviaidentifier = contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Source == "email")?.Identifier?.Trim()?.ToLower();
                        
                if (!contact.Identifiers.Any(x => x.Source == "Alias"))
                {
                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error($"ListCheck {contact.Id} no Alias", this);
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/InvalidEmail.csv"), $"{contact.Id},email,{emailviaidentifier},{email}" + Environment.NewLine);
                    subscriptionService.Unsubscribe(listId, contact.Id.Value);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error($"ListCheck {contact.Id}", ex, this);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error($"ListCheck", ex, this);
    }
}
```

Sitecore support have advised there is no supported way to programmatically add the Alias identifier and the best option is to manually delete and recreate these contacts.